# Navigate from compose to Fragment

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-architecture-navigation, android-navigation

I would like to navigate from compose to a Fragment.  I have defined a NavHost in compose:

```
NavHost(
   navController = navController,
   startDestination = DrawerScreen.Screen2.route
) {
   composable(DrawerScreen.Screen1.route) {
      navController.navigate(R.id.screen_one)
   }
   composable(DrawerScreen.Screen2.route) {
      Screen2(
         openDrawer = {
            openDrawer()
         }
      )
   }
}
```

Simple Fragment:

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class ScreenOneFragment: Fragment() {

   @Nullable
   override fun onCreateView(
      inflater: LayoutInflater,
      @Nullable container: ViewGroup?,
      @Nullable savedInstanceState: Bundle?
   ): View {
      val view: View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.screen_one, container, false)
      return view
   }
}
```

However when I try to navigate I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Navigation action/destination com.test/screenOne cannot be found from the current destination Destination(0x2b264dff) route=ScreenOne
```

Here is my navigation xml:

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mobile_navigation"
    app:startDestination="@id/screenOne">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/screenOne"
        android:name="com.test.ScreenOne"
        android:label="ScreenOne" />
</navigation>
```

Is it possible to navigate from compose to a Fragment?

Comment: You can't use the compose navigator with fragments. You will need to use the view system navigator and host your composables in fragments.

Comment: @Francesc I am really hoping that is not true. 99% of my app is compose and I need one fragment. Seems like a gigantic oversight.

Comment: @lostintranslation If you only need one  `Fragment`, don't use Navigation Component.

Comment: I have multiple compose screens, compose NavHost controls navigation between those screens. I also need to navigate to an regular old android Fragment as well.

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't just [adding your fragment to a composable destination](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/interop/interop-apis#fragments-in-compose)?

Comment: @ianhanniballake mainly because the fragment I am creating is a complex map fragment.  Would be nice create an Android Fragment and use non compose functions to break up the logic.  Also is it possible to call AndroidViewBinding from a NavHost composable function?

Comment: You can do whatever you want inside of a composable destination, including creating a complex map fragment :)

Comment: @ianhanniballake, so sounds like the answer to my question is no.

Answer (score 10):

As per the [Interopability docs](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation#interoperability):

> If you want to use the Navigation component with Compose, you have two options:
>
> - Define a navigation graph with the Navigation component for fragments.
> - Define a navigation graph with a NavHost in Compose using Compose destinations. **This is possible only if all of the screens in the navigation graph are composables.**

So no, you cannot navigate to a fragment destination if you are using a `NavHost` (the reverse is also true: if you are using a `NavHostFragment`, you can't navigate to a `composable` destination: neither world knows about the other).

What it actually sounds like is that you want to [add a Fragment to Compose](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/interop/interop-apis#fragments-in-compose). This would allow all of your destinations to be `composable` destinations in your single `NavHost`, but let one screen be implemented entirely by a fragment (your `ScreenOne`).

```
composable(DrawerScreen.Screen1.route) {
  // Assumes you have a layout with a FragmentContainerView
  // that uses android:name="com.test.ScreenOneFragment"
  AndroidViewBinding(ScreenOneLayoutBinding::inflate) {
    val myFragment = fragmentContainerView.getFragment<ScreenOneFragment>()
    // ...
}
```

}

Comment: This causes a crash when trying to navigate to this destination: `android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2 in .... Error inflating class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView`. Any idea what the problem may be? Navigation to pure composable destinations works fine, there are no actual issues in the xml and I am using a unique id for it.

Comment: @NoHarmDan you would need to use `AppCompatActivity` as base activity if you want to use the AndroidViewBinding. You might also have to fix your theme in case it crashes due to that after using  `AppCompatActivity`